# How to format JSON string in logcat when using Flutter print statement

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am wondering is there any way to view JSON response in formatted manner when using `print()` statement in Android Studio.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866042/android-format-json-string-in-adb-logcat-output) works for Java, where you use `Log.i()`.

How can I get it work when using `print()` function?

Comment: first say what's not working with `print`? long strings are truncated?

Comment: @pskink Hi, I am sorry I may not be able to phrase my query, however the answer provided by a user does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*This works like a charm. :)*

```
String yourJson = '{"code": "0", "text": "hello world"}';

final object = json.decode(yourJson);
final prettyString = JsonEncoder.withIndent('  ').convert(object);

print(prettyString);
```

**Output:**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is this still working? I only get escaped output with all format removed  like this: "[{\"name\":\"0\",\"url\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"11\",\"url\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"2\",\"url\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"3\",\"url\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"4\",\"url\":\"\"}]"